# How to get the managed configuration from the non DPC application?

Tags: android, kiosk, kiosk-mode, android-management-api, device-policy-manager

I have enrolled the device with the enterprise web application and applied the restriction through the Admin(DPC) application.
Now i am trying to get the managed configuration using **RestrictionsManager.getApplicationRestrictions() from the non DPC application**, but i am getting **empty parcel**.

Is there any possibility to get the managed configuration from non DPC application.
Whether i need to do any other configuration to get the managed configuration from our own application.

https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get a managed configuration set for your own application, then I believe your issue has been answered already from this post.

[RestrictionManager getRestrictions() is always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327704/restrictionmanager-getrestrictions-is-always-empty)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot get the managed configuration using non-DPC application. This is privileged permission and only available for device owner. What you can do is to ask your DPC application to expose certain permissions via SDK to third party application that you can use in your non-DPC application.